# Why don't a child's vertical margins expand their parent container?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have come across a case where I need a child's margin to expand a parent container. I found that the space outside of the parent is allocated, but the parent itself is not expanded. I then found that by adding `overflow: hidden` to the parent I could fix this issue.

Can anyone shed any light on why this is the case?

I have found that adding any padding or border value to the parent also fixes this.

```css
section {
    background: black;
    //overflow: hidden; /* toggle this */
    //padding: 1px; /* or toggle this */
    //border: solid 1px green; /* or toggle this */
}

div {
   margin: 10px;
   background: red;    
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>
        SOME CONTENT            
    </div>
</section>
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/wmdXJ/2/)

Comment: Is this the only fix? It's annoying dealing with the consequences of `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: For some theory on this check http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/ and http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: a good explanation of this problem: http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer to "why" is described well and succinctly [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150423190902/http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/). There are certain properties that establish a "[block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)". Namely:

> Floats, absolutely [and fixed] positioned elements, block containers (such as
> inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block
> boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except
> when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new
> block formatting contexts for their contents.

It is this change of block formatting context that is the reason *why* such solutions as given above in the comments work for how `margin` (and in the case of a preceding `float`, `padding` of following inflow elements) operates.

Answer (score 6):

I think collapsing margins is the reason : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 4):

A small update as of July 2018. Mozilla has a [great article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) on this matter which is due to margin collapse.

Summary: Margins of the parent and the first child may collapse. They end up **as if the parent had the resulting margin**.

> **Parent and first/last child**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline part, block formatting context created, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block; or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.